# Heating with tea candles using pot vs. not using a pot

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

With all the concern about loosing regular heating this winter I have been looking at alternative emergency ways to heat up a room. One common suggestion is to use tea lights. So you put six (or so) tea lights on a plate or something. You are then recommended to put a flower pot up-side-down over the tea lights.

[In this video](https://youtu.be/79BlboFE7YA?t=102) (he uses a cooking pot instead of a flower pot) the person explains that putting the pot over the candles will better heat up the room because it heats up the pot that then *radiates* the heat instead of heating using *convection* from the candles alone.

This doesn't make sense to me. My thinking would be that the candles put out the same amount of heat no matter what.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

> My thinking would be that the candles put out the same amount of heat
> no matter what.

Unless the placement of the pot somehow increases the rate of combustion of the candles, then you are right that the rate of heat transfer to the room should be the same.

But there is also the question what type of heating provides more comfort, radiant or convection heating. According to following link, radiant heating provides more comfort; https://energy-com.co.uk/service/radiant-heats-vs-convection-heat/. So if the percentage of the total heat transfer by radiation is greater
with the pot in place then without it, the pot would theoretically provide more comfort for the same total amount of heat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It had to do with the head dispassion, the thermal reservoir alone did not provide much effects after two or three hours in a room but using the molecular as an thermal absorber increased the secondary dispassion and could make the heating system rather efficient.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate I assume you mean "dissipation". Not sure what you mean, but In any case, it still appears that radiation provides the most effective distribution of heat, instead of the heated column of air from the candles alone . The delayed effect probably has to do with the time to heat the pot to its maximum temperature for maximum radiation to occur.

Comment: Yes, but the condition was designed in the thermal equilibrium. Last year my room was running at constant air exchange by using a large box fan to push the air in, but with the aforementioned design, the room temperature was maintained over 80 Fahrenheit mostly, while it's zero outside, with a monthly electric bill of below 200$, but with the calculate placement of a metric ton's of water, the bill was lowered and it felt warmer, so it's more than the process to reach the maximum temperature.

Comment: Air exchange? With what, the outside? I'm still confused.

Comment: Yes. "To maintain a thermal background in a confined space with constant air exchange". The radiative background showed particular advantage than heating up the air molecular in this case. It's more than the OP had considered but basically the physics was the same.

Comment: You should have included in your post the fact that there is air exchange. But even so, I have no idea what you mean by a "thermal background"

Comment: I assumed it was in the OP's assumption, both the candles consumed the oxygen in the air, and in the video link it's in the condition of a room with air exchange(might be at a much slower rate than the box fan though).

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Sorry I thought all along I was responding to the OP's comments. I didn't realize it was a different person.

Answer (score 0):

Because essentially it's about the heat dispassion, the candle flame induced an upward air which resulted a large dispassion through the air, and the air molecular got cooled down much easily. It basically reduced to a linear relation to the exchange rate of the air which might say rather fast.

The pot solution was the black body radiation so the thermal residue could be maintained much longer as it falls off exponentially, and the fact that it's achieve the "warm" by provide the radiative thermal background and not necessarily heat up the air direly.(You might have seen some comment about the energy efficient heaters, etc. That's basically what they were talking about.)

Anyway none of those worked because it had to do with the infrastructure as in the thermal insulation, almost none of the Eurasia or America's houses could retain a heat background with a few tea candle. In an apartment complex, the thermal transfer through the walls were actually more meaningful.